# parent.document IE8 does not work

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I have a same domain iframe within a page that lets users upload unlimited images (with out posting the primary page).  It works flawless with everything minus IE8.

IE8 doesn't throw an error either; any recommendations on how to get this to work?

I.e. within iframe -> parent.document.getEle....appendChild(X);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that IE8's form requires the enctype tag to be filled on page render, it doesn't work when dynamically adding enctype via JavaScript.